# How to make slider inputs with Leaflet and shiny in R?

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, popup, cluster-analysis

I have two dataframes as follows. I have only put partial data for simplicity:

```
**order**
Location     Order_count    Longitude   Latitude
New York      12            74.0060     40.7128
San Francisco 7             122.4194    37.7749
Miami         13            80.1918     25.7617
Texas         20            99.9018     31.9686
Dallas        1             96.7970     32.7767
Mary          0             27.6648     81.5158
Whitney       9             32.3182     86.9023

**arrivals**
Cust_id  Arrival_time   Location
1         3             New York
2         18            Miami
3         20            Texas
4          1            New York
5          0            Dallas
6         18            Miami
7         20            Dallas
8          1            New York
```

1. At first, I mapped the locations on a leaflet using symbols by the longitude and latitude from order dataframe.
2. Then I have put a selection slider that selects arrival_time. Based on the time selected, the number of customers on that location (on the map) should change. The map also shows total arrivals over all times in that particular location. For example, if I select Arrival_time=1, if I click New York on the map, it should say,
   "New York",

   "Number of customers for the selected time: 2",

   "Total number of customers: 3".

I have coded in the following ways:

```
**ui**
shinyUI(fluidpage(
  titlePanel("Time"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("time", "Hours selected ", min=0, max=24, value=12)
    ), 
    
    mainPanel()),
  leafletOutput("mymap", height = "900", width = "900")))

**server**


shinyServer(function(input, output){
  
  data_input <- reactive({arrivals%>% 
      filter(Arrival_time== input$time) %>% 
      group_by(Location) %>% count()
  })
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data=order) %>% addTiles() %>% 
      
      addMarkers(~Longitude, ~Latitude, popup = paste(order$Location,
      "Total arrivals for the selected time: ", arrivals$data_input," 
       order$Order_count))
  })})
```

The map does not change with the input provided from the slider. I don't know where I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Please don't vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/) license, for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed, and thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/what-to-do-instead-of-deleting-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `arrivals$data_input` by `data_input()$n`

EDIT : based on our comments, your initial problem looks more like merging your different datasets

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
library(dplyr)

order <- data.frame(
  Location = c('New York', 'San Francisco', 'Miami', 'Texas', 'Dallas', 'Mary', 'Whitney'),
  Order_count = c(12, 7, 13, 20, 1, 0 ,9),   
  Longitude = c(-74.0060, -122.4194, -80.1918, -99.9018, -96.7970, -81.5158, -86.9023),
  Latitude = c(40.7128, 37.7749, 25.7617, 31.9686, 32.7767, 27.6648, 32.3182)
)

arrivals = data.frame(
  Cust_id  = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8),
  Arrival_time = c(3,18,20,1,0,18,20,1),
  Location = c('New York', 'Miami', 'Texas', 'New York', 'Dallas', 'Miami', 'Dallas', 'New York')
)


# Make a dataframe containing needed variables by merging data
join_data <- order %>%
  inner_join(arrivals %>% 
              group_by(Location, Arrival_time) %>% 
              summarise(number_of_customer = n()),
            by = "Location") %>%
  left_join(arrivals %>% 
              group_by(Location) %>% 
              summarise(total_number_of_customer = n()),
            by = "Location")

ui <- shinyUI(fixedPage(
  titlePanel("Time"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput("time", "Hours selected ", min=0, max=24, value=1)
    ), 
    
    mainPanel()),
  leafletOutput("mymap", height = "900", width = "900")))



server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session){
  
  data_input <- reactive({
    join_data %>%
      filter(Arrival_time==input$time)
  })
  
  output$mymap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data=order) %>% 
      addTiles() %>% 
      addMarkers(
        ~Longitude, 
        ~Latitude, 
        popup = paste(
          order$Location, "<br>",
          "Number of customers for the selected time ", data_input()$number_of_customer," 
          <br>","Total number of customers: ", data_input()$total_number_of_customer))
  })})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hey, its not working.

Comment: what is not working ? you have an error ?

Comment: It is just not showing the correct values on the map. Showing incorrect values. Don't know why.

Comment: Depends on what you want to show. Your question says "Number of customers for the selected time" and "Total number of customers", your code says "Total arrivals for the selected time" and ""Total arrivals". i can only correct the technical mistakes, not the functionnals ones. If so, this is more a dplyr problem than a shiny problem. I corrected the shiny problem i found

Comment: I think the problem is because the arrivals data does not have a longitude and latitude value, so does not know which location to tag, do you know how to fix this?

Comment: yes, i will update my post

Comment: You're a life saviour :-D